# How to fetch records according to SYSTIMESTAMP using Hibernate/Oracle11g

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I have a field named end_time (of type timestamp(6)) in my Oracle 11g DB. My requirement is to fetch records which are greater than current time stamp.As I work with remote DB, I need the current time of my oracle database server.

After some research I came to know that **SYSTIMESTAMP** returns current time stamp of machine where DB resides.

So I just put a condition like end_time > SYSTIMESTAMP, but it does not filter records. My end-time is of type timestamp(6).

Do I have to use any conversion function? How can I do it from Hibernate? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you further explain on "does not filter records", are too many rows in your result or to few?

Your condition looks absolutely ok:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ts TIMESTAMP(6));
INSERT INTO mytable (ts) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2012-12-06 17:00:00');
INSERT INTO mytable (ts) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2012-12-06 18:00:00');

SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
 06.12.2012 17:10:38.347629000 +01:00

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ts > SYSTIMESTAMP;
06.12.2012 18:00:00.000000000

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ts < SYSTIMESTAMP;
06.12.2012 17:00:00.000000000
```

Comment: My question was, do I have to use any conversion function to compare dates? I felt records are not filtering properly. I will cross verify. What is the type of SYSTIMESTAMP? Is it timestamp(6)? If so I do not want explicit coversion as my end_time is of type timestamp(6).right?

Comment: Yes, SYSTIMESTAMP has the datatype TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE.